# Bound Of Complex Contour Integral

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $$\gamma:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$$ be a path and $$f:\gamma([0,1])\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
a continuous function. I'm trying to prove that
$$\left|\int_\gamma f\right|\leq \int_\gamma |f|.$$
First of all, $|f|$ is continuous in $\gamma([0,1])$, so this is well defined. I know
$$\left|\int_\gamma f\right|=\int_0^1 \Re\left(e^{-i\theta}(f\circ \gamma)\gamma'\right),$$
where $\theta$ is an argument of $\int_\gamma f$. But I don't even know if this is helpful. How could one prove this?

Comment: What you are trying to prove is not true. Consider for example $f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$ and integrate this over the unit circle.

Comment: You're right! I really thought this property was true because I have a book that uses it all over the place. I'm surely getting rid of it!

Answer (score 1):

Really you can just apply the triangle inequality over the Riemann integral: $$\left|\int_0^1f(\gamma)\gamma’\right|\le\int_0^1|f(\gamma)\gamma’|$$Which is valid as the triangle inequality applies to all partial Riemann sums and as such extends to the limit, the integral.

Comment: But shouldn't we get $\int_0^1 |f(\gamma)|\gamma'$ in the RHS instead of $\int_0^1 |f(\gamma)\gamma'|$?

Comment: @AndrésCárcel No. In the *Riemann* integral I am simply integrating the function $t\mapsto f(\gamma(t))\gamma’(t)$. The triangle inequality, if used, must be applied to the whole thing, the summand or the integrand, so the bound is by $|f(\gamma(t))\gamma’(t)|$

Comment: @AndrésCárcel In some texts you might see this notation: $$\oint_\gamma|f(z)|\,|\mathrm{d}z|$$And the $|\mathrm{d}z|$ shall refer to the term $|\gamma’(t)|$ in the Riemann integral

Comment: I know this notation, but this is not the case of my book! My book uses $|\int_\gamma f(z)dz|\leq \int_\gamma |f(z)|dz$.